# Removing old java paths - Puppet

Tags: path, environment-variables, puppet

We are having an issue with the puppet java modules. They are adding the correct path, but they do not remove the old path:

> C:\Windows\system32>path
>   PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NTP\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_50\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\apache-maven\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin

You can see that it added the correct path at the end, but the original version jdk1.7_50\bin still exists. How can we make sure that it removes the old version every time it installs a newer version?

Edit: More importantly what we need to do is have it search for the `JAVA_HOME` path variable, compare that against `Path` variable, delete any java directory that doesnt belong, and copy the `JAVA_HOME` to `Path`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: What manifest is causing the perceived misbehavior? What action has Puppet taken, and what did you expect instead?

Comment: The standard java manifest for windows.  The one with the most downloads.  It adds the correct NEW java path to the Path variable.  It also correctly appends to JAVA_HOME.   However, it does not remove old Path variable for java directories.  So when a new version is installed, it just adds the new directory to the end, whilst the old directory stays as well.

Comment: I was getting at the manifest that you had written which incorporates the module you mentioned (but didn't [link](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/java) ;-) It's fine, I think I can see your issue now.

Comment: Sorry.  I did not write it.  I am on Week 2 of Puppet.  Was kind of thrown into it at work and told to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

The [puppetlabs-java](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/java) module does not seem to make an effort to update the default environment.

I believe that the behavior you are observing results from actions taken by the Java installer itself.

If you can find out where Java puts the commands to append to the `PATH`, you may be able to have Puppet remove the obsolete lines using the `file_line` type from the [stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) module.

**Edit** after you supplied the manifest that handles the path:

If your paths are managed through [this module](https://github.com/basti1302/puppet-windows-path), you will need to add resources to your manifest to remove each single obsolete entry, such as:

```
windows_path {
   'java7u50': 
       ensure => absent,
       directory => 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_50\bin';
}
```

To simplify this for many versions, you can create a defined type:

```
define obsolete_java {
    windows_path {
       $name: 
           ensure => absent,
           directory => "C:\Program Files\Java\$name\bin";
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
obsolete_java { [ 'jdk1.7.0_50', 'jdk1.7.0_42', ... ]: }
```

Comment: `# Adds java to the path.
    windows_path {'javaPath':
      ensure      => present,
      directory   => "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\$file\\bin",
    }

I know you can change this to 

ensure =>  'absent'
directory  =>  "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\$file\\bin"
`
and it will remove an entry, but it doesnt seem to remove all java path entries.

Comment: This is why I asked for your manifest in my comment - it was not clear from your quesiton **at all** that you were doing such a thing.

Comment: Updated the answer with a possible strategy.

Comment: gotta love only getting a few days to understand the syntax.
I attempted to add what you suggested but just get plagued with errors.

I feel like a complete idiot right now.  Im sure that will change in the upcoming weeks when I learn the syntax, but for now, this is my first edit ever.  This was someone elses work that left the company and handed to me.   Thanks for your help and patience.

https://github.com/tek0011/Puppet/blob/master/test.pp

Comment: Error: Could not parse for environment production: Cannot nest definition obsolete_java inside windows_java::setup at /etc/puppet/modules/windows_java/manifests/setup.pp:13

Comment: *sigh* OK, so it's the `windows_java` module. That's good to know. - Don't edit the module directly. Add the proposed code where `windows_java::setup` is being used in the machine's manifest (e.g. `windows_java::setup { 'java': source => ... }`). - The cause for the error is that a `define` block cannot be located inside the body of another `define` (in this case, you're trying to do it inside `define windows_java::setup`).

Comment: thank you very much.  I can express to you how grateful I am.  Boss assigned me this task about a week ago, which was close to the first time I had even heard of Puppet.  For whatever reason, I added the define that you gave me before my other define, and it worked exactly as expected.   I also learned alot from it.

Now on a side note, 
Is there a way in puppet to just have this:
`obsolete_java { [ 'jdk1.7.0_50', 'jdk1.7.0_42', ... ]: }`
do a search for anything, kind of like:
`obsolete_java { [ 'jdk1.7*']: }`

So it would just look for anything named jdk1.7xxxx ?

Comment: You're most welcome. Please open new questions for any followup issues. If my answer helped you, please consider voting and accepting it ;-)

Comment: unfortunately I dont have enough "reputation" to upvote it :(